# Is it possible to purchase quantum computing hardware?

Tags: architecture, experimental-realization

Are there schematics and/or diagrams out there to build a very basic quantum system?

Comment: For the record, this asks two different questions, one in the title and one in the body, and both are rather broad and localized. You may wish to edit the question.

Comment: @rrtucci added a comment: "You could buy one from Google" and I asked if you could purchase a Bristlecone and it was removed.  Why was this removed from the post?

Comment: comments are by their nature epheremal. If a comment doesn't ask for clarification or enhance the understanding of the question, it is open to deletion. Among other things, comments are not places for asking new, unrelated questions.

Comment: @rrtucci's comment was a jesting way of pointing out that this question is meaningless without some constraint. After all what if someone had enough money to buy out such a large company.

Answer (score 5):

I think this kind of depends on what you are looking for. You asked about building a basic quantum system which you can totally do*. Just grab a good laser, single photon detectors, beam splitters and wave plates, and some attenuating filters. If you can get the laser down to a trickle of single photons you can do some fun quantum key distribution demos, and operations on single qubits (possibly on pairs if you have the right components). Now, that's obviously no computer, but since computers are built out of qubits its a start.
Also as @peterh mentioned, there is lots of simulators that you can use if you want to work with more qubits now, and example being [Q#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_Sharp) that actually can estimate the number of qubits you would need to run your algorithm on a real quantum computer.

- This is still gonna be a couple thousand dollars or more, but not nearly as much as a D-Wave :) Here is a "demo" system from an overpriced lab equipment store: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=9869

Answer (score 2):

The only commercially available quantum machines are from a  company called [D-Wave](https://www.dwavesys.com/home) however there is debate on exactly how "quantum" their machines are.

True quantum computers in the way most of the community looks at them are not available for physical purchase, although IBM's [Q Experience](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx) allows you to use their quantum computing resources through the cloud.

In terms of trying to DIY a quantum computer we are a long way from such a goal being viable.

Comment: Are simpler systems available? https://hackaday.com/2018/01/22/quantum-computing-hardware-teardown/

Comment: Not really. As your article mentions D-Wave uses Josephson Junctions, and trapping ions is exceedingly non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that they are currently experiments in different labs, with the [record](https://thenextweb.com/artificial-intelligence/2018/03/06/google-reclaims-quantum-computer-crown-with-72-qubit-processor/) of around 72 qubit, they are yet very far from a product which can be sold.

However, you can choose from a [long list](https://quantiki.org/wiki/list-qc-simulators) of different emulators/simulators.